# Imprimir valores de 1 a N

Tags: java

Quero comecar a testar um codigo e para isso eu queria que ele comecasse imprimindo valores de 1 a N.

exemplo:

entrada: 7

saida: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: Mas qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Não negativem a questão pois o usuário está buscando um ponto de partida para conhecer a linguagem.

Comment: SIIIM, tou no inicio

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in); //valor recebido pelo usuario

    for(int i=0; i<entrada; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
}// FIM DO PROGRAMA
```

veja se dá certo.

Comment: +1 pelo scanner e elaboração. Eu teria deixado apenas `for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)`.

Comment: Cabe ressaltar aqui que a intenção era intervalo `[1,N]`, não [0,N)`. Você poderia ter tratado disso de 2 maneiras distintas pelo menos. Também tem o ponto que, se for uma validação automática que exija tudo em uma única linha, sua resposta daria erro de formato (por ter impresso em linhas distintas e, também, por não ter colocado as vírgulas). Também tem o fato de que `i < entrada` não faz muito sentido sendo `entrada` do tipo  `Scanner`, mas creio que isso foi um erro de digitação e que você desejava fazer `int entrada = scan.nextInt()`

Comment: @LucasNascimentoTávora, se essa é a resposta adequada para o seu problema, não se esqueça de marcá-la como aceita.